# Sync crosshair on multiple charts using FLOT

Tags: jquery, flot

I am trying to sync the crosshair across three flot charts. I haven't been able to find any examples with the one exception of a somewhat similar example in the comment section of the crosshair.js file. Here is a snippet of my code, I am trying to initialize the plots here. Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
var covariancePlot = $.plot($("#covarianceChartContainer"), [ 0,0 ], {crosshair: { mode: "x" }, xaxis:{ mode: "time"}});
var observationPlot = $.plot($("#observationChartContainer"), [ 0,0 ], {crosshair: { mode: "x" }, xaxis:{ mode: "time"}});
var collisionPlot = $.plot($("#collisionChartContainer"), [ 0,0 ], {crosshair: { mode: "x" }, xaxis:{ mode: "time"}});

$("#covarianceChartContainer").bind("plothover", function (event, pos) {
     //sync crosshairs of the other two plots
     observationPlot.setCrosshair(pos.x);
     collisionPlot.setCrosshair(pos.x);
});
$("#observationChartContainer").bind("plothover", function (event, pos) {
     //sync crosshairs of the other two plots
     covariancePlot.setCrosshair(pos.x);
     collisionPlot.setCrosshair(pos.x);
});
$("#collisionChartContainer").bind("plothover", function (event, pos) {
     //sync crosshairs of the other two plots
     observationPlot.setCrosshair(pos.x);
     covariancePlot.setCrosshair(pos.x);
});
```

Turns out there are two problems with the above code, one is the grid: {hoverable: true}, statement is missing from the options for each of the plots. The other is the setCrosshair() function expects the full position variable not just the x value stored in pos.x. Hopefully, I can save someone else from the frustration I experienced.

Comment: You did save me a lot of grief. Thanks. +1